# How to insert array into sqlitedatabase column and how to show in Uitableview cell

Tags: mysql, objective-c, arrays, sqlite

How to insert array into sqlitedatabase column and how to show in Uitableview cell.

Here iam showing data in tableview in that selected cell data saving in one array(selectedDataArray) . How to store the selectedDataArray in sqlite database. any body hlpme code.

Comment: Help you with code?  Do your homework by running a search and help yourself.

Comment: stack is not for 'code on demand'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQlite doesn't support array to insert.

Convert the array into string and insert to db.

NSString *arrayString = [self.someArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];

[managedObject setValue:arrayString forKey:@"xyz"];

After fetching the string from db and convert to array.

NSArray *savedArray = [arrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Now you will display array values in uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

SQlite doesn't support array to  insert. see the below link.
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html